# How can I use hover in a child without the parent's hover being activated?

Tags: css, html, hover, parent-child

My code can add `div`s as child or sibling, I've created two classes and two `:hover` for each class but when I put the mouse on a child the parent hover is activated as well.

```css
.Group {
  background-color: white;
}

.Group2 {
  background-color: white;
}

.Group:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Group2:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Group">
  root
  <div class="Group">1st child
    <div class="Group2">2nd child
      <div class="Group">3rd child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Group">1st child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you hover over `.Group2`, what is suppose to happen? only the red background is activated?

Comment: yes, but it show the two parents as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faking the :has() "parent selector" using only CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393931/faking-the-has-parent-selector-using-only-css)

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over a child element, you're also hovering over the parent, there's no way around that.

What you could do is set a different or additional class on the 1st child elements that don't have further children.

Comment: but as you can see for the 2nd child with a different class, the problem isn't solved, i tried to use p instead of div and it works, but doesn't look a good solution

Answer (score 2):

### Highlighting background colors in nested blocks when hovering

If you are trying to activate the background colors of the nested `div` blocks, I think you might be looking for the following.

For the **HTML**, use distinct class names to identify each layer of nested `div` blocks:

```
<div class="Group">root
    <div class="Group1">1st child
        <div class="Group2">2nd child
            <div class="Group3">3rd child</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Group1">1st child</div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```css
.Group, .Group1, .Group2, .Group3 {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.Group:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.Group1:hover {
    background-color:pink;
}
.Group2:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
.Group3:hover {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Scr9G/

As you mouse over each nested `div` successively, the background color changes in sequence.

**If you are trying to target a nested element with `:hover` without the effect bubbling up through the parent/ancestor blocks, you will need to use JavaScript/jQuery to create the selection rules that you need.**

### Quirky Hack Using `<p>` Tags

The following construction exhibits the behavior that the OP would like to see:

```
<p class="Group">root
    <p class="Group">1st child
        <p class="Group2">2nd child
            <p class="Group">3rd child</p>
        </p>
    </p>
    <p class="Group">1st child</p>
</p>
```

and the CSS is as before:

```css
.Group {
    background-color:white;
}
.Group2 {
    background-color:white;
}
.Group:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.Group2:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Second demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cf2mn/

In this case, the OP was trying to nest `<p>` tags, which actually do not work like nesting other block elements like `<div>`.

When using `<p>` tags, the closing `</p>` tag is optional if followed by other flow elements like `p`, `div`, `ul` and so on.

In this case, the HTML snippet show above is equivalent to:

```
<p class="Group">root</p>
<p class="Group">1st child</p>
<p class="Group2">2nd child</p>
<p class="Group">3rd child</p>
<p class="Group">1st child</p>
```

which means that all the `p` tabs are siblings and there are no parent-child relationships, which is why the CSS appears to be working as the OP desired.

If `div` tags had been used instead of `p` tags, the resulting DOM would have exhibited the parent-child relationships and the CSS would have shown the original behavior that the OP did not want.

Using the `p` tags may give the desired effect for the CSS, but it works only because the DOM elements are siblings instead of parent-child. (In addition, the nested `p` tags will not validate.)

It is worth noting that:

> CSS 2.1 does not define if the parent of an element that is ':active' or ':hover' is also in that state.

so it is better not to rely on the state of the parent element when apply a pseudo-element on a child element.

**References:**

About `:hover`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

About optional closing of `p` tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p

Comment: actually i'd like to have this result:http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/2127/ but as we know we cannot have one <p>: inside an otherone

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent parent elements to get background color.. rather  use this code

```
<div class="root">
Main Root
<div class="group">
    First One
</div>
<div class="group2">
    Second One
</div>
<div class="group">
    Third One
</div>
```

```
.group:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
.group2:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/2125/)

Comment: but if I've got one other child as is 2nd child or 3rd child in my example, your solution doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Give separate ids to the divs and when a child div is hovered over, change its background image color and remove the background color of the parent all at the same time. I guess that is the only way around this

Comment: my problem is that, I've created the child dynamically than i'm not sure i can create the css run time to create the nwChildId:hover

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way is probably to use any other element, li for instance.

css:

```
.Group, .Group2, .Group3
{
background:white;
display: block;
list-style: none;
}
.parent
{
margin: 0;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}
.Group:hover
{
background: yellow;
}
.Group2:hover
{
background: red;
}
.Group3:hover
{
background: yellow;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="parent" >
<li class="Group" >root
  <li class="Group">1st child
    <li class="Group2">2nd child
      <li class="Group3">3rd child</li>
    </li >
  </li >
  <li class="Group">1st child</li >
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The closing tag on the `li` tag is optional.  In this case, you essentially have made all the `li` tags behave like sibling child elements of the `ul.parent` block.  This HTML snippet will not validate.

Answer (score 0):

You should add sub-element for content and use [element+element](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) pseudo selector.

```css
.group-content:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.group-content:hover + .group {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="group-content">1st child</div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="group-content">2nd child</div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-content">3nd child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="group-content">1st child</div>
</div>
```