# Faking the :has() "parent selector" using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It's long been hailed as the answer to many selector problems, even disputed by some as entirely unnecessary, but the Selectors Level 4 pseudo-class **`:has()`**, better known as the **parent selector**, is the *only* one from Level 4 that will not be implemented in CSS, according to the latest revision of the **[W3 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles)**. Reason being that it's inefficient and already covered by JavaScript functionality.

Mulling over this, I've been thinking of how to fake this effect using pure CSS. Below I've provided one method, Q&A style, for achieving the effect as an answer, but would like to know if there are other methods. Specifically, more efficient CSS implementations, or responsive CSS implementations.

Comment: Note that it is still open to (and required for conformance in) implementations outside CSS, which means stuff like `querySelectorAll()` can potentially benefit without having to depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Gecko and WebKit, certain selectors can “jump” using `<label for>` and an associated `<input>` element positioned anywhere. This works unreliably, but is still kind of fun.

```css
#before {
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
}
#parent {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
#before:hover + #parent {
    background-color: #123;
    color: white;
}
#label {
    border: 0.1em solid #678;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="before">

<div id="parent">
    <label for="before" id="label">Hover over me!</label>
</div>
```

(You might have to click once if using Chrome.)

Comment: The checkbox hack strikes again - works in FF as well by the way

Comment: @ZachSaucier: It’s a different one, though! I hope I’m the first to find it. … probably not.

Comment: @false Nice answer! I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else puts forward an answer; if not, this will get the checkmark for sure.

Comment: An explanation of some of my findings on this behavior and why it works in certain browsers and not others can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098581/why-is-hover-for-input-triggered-on-corresponding-label-in-css/9101344#9101344).

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/95HKP/embedded/result/)**

For this method, I created a fixed-position container element of static size, with a single child element inside of it, taking up 200px by 200px.

Then, I added two absolutely-positioned elements (`.glass1` and `.glass2`) to simulate glass panes ("You can look, but you can't touch"), and I used `z-index` on them so that they would cover the remaining space of the container element.

The addition of these glass panes is to simulate the effect of nothing happening unless you hover over the child. Otherwise this method wouldn't imitate parent selector behavior; it would just be a normal `:hover` implementation.

At this point, it was just a matter of adding a `:hover` property to the container that did not affect the area covered by the child element.

```css
.container {
    background: lavender;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.glass1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.glass2 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
}
.hover {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.container:hover:not(.hover) {
    background: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover">Hover over me. Change my parent.</div>
</div>
<div class="glass1"></div>
<div class="glass2"></div>
```

The obvious problem with this implementation is its static nature and its lack of responsiveness. A more-practiced hand might allow for some measure of responsiveness.

Edit: [More efficient version](http://jsfiddle.net/95HKP/2/) by ZachSaucier

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what I mentioned in comments – instead of the element that gets hovered over *actually* being a child element, it is a mere sibling that comes right *before* the element that should be affected – and the *adjacent sibling combinator* is used to affect the second element on hover of the first one,

```
.hover:hover ~ .container {
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95HKP/5/embedded/result/

Since it has no need for additional positioned elements “covering up” the second element, it does not suffer from the mentioned drawbacks, such as actual content in the second element not being accessible via mouse cursor for selection or other forms of interaction. Only the “triggering” element itself is positioned absolutely over the other one – instead of using absolute positioning, other methods to achieve that are possible as well, f.e. a negative `margin-bottom`.
(And I have introduced a “spacer” element to keep the content from being overlapped by the absolutely positioned element – that does not necessarily need an additional element, for example a pseudo element created using `::before` would do as well.)

So again, this is also *not* a “parent selector” – just something that achieves a certain *effect* by using some positioning and other, broadly available selectors.

Comment: Same approach (minus the added filler text) as the version by Zach that I linked at the bottom of my answer earlier (this was originally my approach before my browser crashed and I lost my work), and good thing that it's not a parent selector, or it wouldn't be answering the question (which explicitly asks for implementations that fake the same effect as a parent selector. +1.