# styling parent div in css whilst over a child

Tags: css

I am trying to style the parent div when hover over a div but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my work

```css
.icon-grid:hover ~ .ab_section_element {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div data-v-714a5b85="" class="ab_section_element">
  <span data-v-714a5b85="" class="icon icon-grid clickable">
  Section (Left Text)
  </span>
</div>
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your example only works for an element which is on the same level, since you are trying to style a parent element, there is currently no way to do this in CSS, please have a look at this similar post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) , from what I read in the provided post it looks like support for this is in the works

Comment: Could you do it by javascript or do you must use CSS?

Comment: I can easily do it by JS. CSS is the what I trying to achieve

Comment: Your selector selects the `.ab_section_element` element that comes after the hovered `.icon-grid` element on the same level: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faking the :has() "parent selector" using only CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393931/faking-the-has-parent-selector-using-only-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select the parent element, but you can "fake" the selection of the parent element with an absolutely positioned pseudo-element:

```css
.ab_section_element {
  position: relative;
}
.icon-grid:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* just for demonstration */
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div data-v-714a5b85="" class="ab_section_element">
  <span data-v-714a5b85="" class="icon icon-grid clickable">
  Section (Left Text)
  </span>
</div>
```

However, this approach requires that the child element itself shouldn't be positioned (non-statically).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style a parent with hover, but you can do an adjacent.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}

.div1:hover~.div2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
```

Comment: This is not going to solve the OP's question. Not even sure why this is getting upvoted.

Comment: What does the `~` means?

Comment: @AAShakil - it is the _sibling_ selector ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/10782054/17300

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

```
.ab_section_element .icon-grid:hover{
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: white;
}
```